# Is a yeast starter required for this recipe

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, pitch

According to brewers-friend, I am short [139 billion yeast cells](http://www.brewersfriend.com/yeast-pitch-rate-and-starter-calculator/?og=1.068&units=metric&batchsize=20&sugarscale=sg&pitchrate=1.0&yeasttype=dry) for a recipe I was estimating. I was planning on trying something along the lines of [this recipe](https://byo.com/fruit-beer/item/1184-northern-india-pale-ale).

My original idea was to re-hydrate a packet of Safale S04 and chuck it in. Most of my brews had an F.G between 1.010 to 1.015 but I have not brewed a beer with this high of an O.G

Is brewers-friend being a bit conservative with their estimates or should I take some action to guarantee a good F.G?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be best if you included the target OG and the recipe link in the actual text/body of your question, for future reference and ease of readability. The question only makes sense with respect to the link you included. You also can't count on that link existing permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a couple things.  One, don't make a starter for dry yeast.  It has many more cells than liquid so a starter isn't needed.  In addition, dry yeast is coated with a nutrient and if you make a starter that nutrient won't be available in your beer.  Second, the OG isn't all that high.  A single pack of rehydrated dry yeast will be plenty.  Make it easy on yourself.

Comment: Brewers-friend just making me paranoid!

Comment: Side question, why do some tin packs like Brewferm suggest hydrating their brand of dried yeast in small cup of water? I some times do and sometimes don't.

Comment: That's like asking if the chicken or the egg came first!  I've never heard a good explanation of the variance, other than people often rehydrate at too high a temp and kill the yeast.